# Error building IoTivity for Android on Windows

Tags: android, boost, iotivity

I am trying to build IoTivity for Android, in a Windows environment.  I've set up all the dependencies according to https://wiki.iotivity.org/android_build_instructions, but get the following error:

EnvironmentError: Host platform (win32) is currently not supported for boost builds.

The command I'm using to build is:

```
scons TARGET_OS=android TARGET_ARCH=armeabi TARGET_TRANSPORT=ALL RELEASE=1 SECURED=0 ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\jg\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\jg\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle ANDROID_GRADLE="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1\bin\gradle"
```

It appears to be a problem with boost.  How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently build IoTivity for Android on Windows. I've been pushing for this too, but you'll have to do it on Linux or MacOS for now.